# Displaying the selected value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am using bootstrap btngroup to select one value ..how can i display that selected value ?? here is my code.

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <div id="radioBtn" class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" data-toggle="fun" data-  title="Y">YES</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="fun" data-title="X">I don't know</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="fun" data-title="N">NO</a>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="fun" id="fun">
    </div>
```

and JS

```
   $('#radioBtn a').on('click', function(){
      var sel = $(this).data('title');
      var tog = $(this).data('toggle');
      $('#'+tog).prop('value', sel);

     $('a[data-toggle="'+tog+'"]').not('[data-  title="'+sel+'"]').removeClass('active').addClass('notActive');
     $('a[data-toggle="'+tog+'"][data-title="'+sel+'"]').removeClass('notActive').addClass('active');
  })
```

Comment: display where exactly ?

Comment: any where in some div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Tidy your code - remove the spaces in your `data-  title` attribute, in both the HTML and JS, as these are causing it to break.
2. Add a `<div id="display"></div>` in your HTML somewhere and style it how you like.
3. Add this line to your JS click handler: `$('#display').html(sel);`

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4DyEd/).

If you'd prefer the result to be the text of the radio button instead of the value, use `$('#display').html($(this).html());` instead in step 3.

Done.

Comment: how can i set a default value for my div that changes on further selections

Comment: No worries. [Googling "bootstrap btn-group default"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=bootstrap+btn-group+default) has a few ideas. If you struggle you'll need to open a new question specific to that problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but to get the value (or text) from a clicked button in a button group, I use for example.....

**HTML**

```
  <div id="aBtnGroup" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" value="L" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
    <button type="button" value="M" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
    <button type="button" value="R" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  </div>
  <p>
  <div>Selected Val:  <span id="selectedVal"></span></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Get click event, assign button to var, and get values from that var
  $('#aBtnGroup button').on('click', function() {
    var thisBtn = $(this);

    thisBtn.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    var btnText = thisBtn.text();
    var btnValue = thisBtn.val();
    console.log(btnText + ' - ' + btnValue);

    $('#selectedVal').text(btnValue);
  });

  // You can use this to set default value upon document load
  // It will fire above click event which will do the updates for you
  $('#aBtnGroup button[value="M"]').click();
});
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
Left - L
Middle - M
Right - R
```

Hope this helps

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z5cT3xLc4WPClLuMgDeI?p=preview) here

Comment: how can i set default value from one of them?

Comment: You mean you want a button to be set as default in the html? You can just add the 'active' class to that button. You might want to add and remove the active class then though using JQ. I've updated the Plunker, take a look.